# What Database Is Better To Use For Web-Based Operations?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

My problem is that I am currently Making A SERVER machine that is suppose to host the web apps powered by ASP.NET C# and desktop apps that all connect to the server.

What database should I use?

PROS and CONS really Appreciated...

My Selection:

MYSQL,
Microsoft SQL Server,
ORACLE

Comment: Use whatever you are  comfortable with or can get your hands on ...

Comment: I have basic knowledge on both mysql and mssql... if you wouldnt mind me asking.. which of the three is better in terms of efficiency?

Comment: There is rarely a "A is always better than B" (if so, everybody would just use A and noone use B). So it always depends on your particular usecase. For smaller projects (lets say less than 100 simple queries per second), there will be pretty much no difference.

Comment: all the database is efficient it all up to in your hand how you implement and normalized and if you want to save money then you can go with MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments described , both are very good and it depends on what you want. However most people use Mysql for web development. I guess ( in my opinion) because the price of mysql is cheaper and its good for small projects , they dont need the features oracle offeres ( oracle offers many features for functions and performance tuning ).

Anyway check this sites for more info if you want [oracle documnetaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#CHDIIBJH) or [Mysql vs Oracel](http://itxdesign.com/mysql-vs-oracle/)